# Is it valid to make an assumption that directly contradicts a given premise?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Is it valid to make an assumption that directly contradicts a given premise?
For example, if I want to deduct the proposition

$$¬(p→q) ⊢ p∧¬q$$

I'd like to assume $p→q$, so I can falsify things based on the assumption at any given time, but I'm not sure if it's even allowed to continue assumptions once they're evident as contradictions.

Comment: You're free to make a subproof with premise $p\to q$, there's nothing wrong with that. If you end up proving what you want, that's a different matter and it depends on what exactly you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can assume $p → q$, but you will not go very far ...

1) $\lnot (p → q)$ premise

2) $p→q$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 2)

4) $\lnot (p→q)$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\lnot$-introduction, discharging [a]

and we are back to the start.

---

What we need is :

1) $\lnot (p → q)$ premise

2) $\lnot (p \land \lnot q)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $p$ assumed [b]

4) $\lnot q$ --- assumed [c]

5) $p \land \lnot q$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\land$-introduction

6) $\bot$ --- form 2) and 5)

7) $\lnot \lnot q$ --- from 4) and 6) by $\lnot$-introduction, discharging [c]

8) $q$ --- from 7) by *Double Negation*

9) $p \rightarrow q$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\rightarrow$-introduction, discharging [b]

10) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 9)

11) $\lnot \lnot (p \land \lnot q)$ --- from 2) and 10) by $\lnot$-introduction, discharging [a]

> 12) $p \land \lnot q$ --- from 11) by *Double Negation*.